# Swift 5: CoreLocation Error in Xcode 12 on M1 Chip

Tags: ios-simulator, core-location, swift5, xcode12, apple-silicon

I just try to display user location on the map in my application. Here is the code of my single view controller

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    fileprivate let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }
}
```

But when I try to set showsUserLocation to true, I get such error:

**2021-03-01 15:40:13.158237+0300 Test[3618:220718] [MKCoreLocationProvider] CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x600003799a20>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x60000079d3b0> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"**

So, I have tried solutions like ***"set location to custom, not to none in simulator"*** or ***"allow location simulation in scheme options"***, nothing helps.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationManagerDelegate must be declared.

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

...some code...

}

You can do this by implementing the CLLocationManagerDelegate method locationManager(_:didFailWithError:), which will be called if the location manager fails to obtain the user's location.